# XSLT for denormalizing XML

Tags: xml, xslt, ssis, xslt-1.0

I am working with XML import task to denormalised file using XSLT in SSIS. Following is the XML contents.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ReceiptConfirmation>
   <File>
      <FileNumber>11520</FileNumber>
      <FileCreationDate>2014-02-11</FileCreationDate>
      <FileCreationTime>20:50:23</FileCreationTime>
   </File>
   <Receipts>
      <Receipt>
         <InboundID>2136</InboundID>
         <ReceiptID>R00706</ReceiptID>
         <Vendor>DayMen</Vendor>
         <ReceiptDate>2013-12-11</ReceiptDate>
         <ReceiptTime>11:32:21</ReceiptTime>
         <ReceiptType>RMA</ReceiptType>
         <PartReceipts>
            <PartReceipt>
               <PartRef>JB00128-CEN</PartRef>
               <QtyExpected>2</QtyExpected>
               <QtyReceived>0</QtyReceived>
               <StockStatus>Inspection</StockStatus>
            </PartReceipt>
            <PartReceipt>
               <PartRef>JB01259-BWW</PartRef>
               <QtyExpected>2</QtyExpected>
               <QtyReceived>2</QtyReceived>
               <StockStatus>Inspection</StockStatus>
            </PartReceipt>
            <PartReceipt>
               <PartRef>JB01257-BWW</PartRef>
               <QtyExpected>1</QtyExpected>
               <QtyReceived>1</QtyReceived>
               <StockStatus>Inspection</StockStatus>
            </PartReceipt>
            <PartReceipt>
               <PartRef>JB01112-BWW</PartRef>
               <QtyExpected>3</QtyExpected>
               <QtyReceived>3</QtyReceived>
               <StockStatus>Inspection</StockStatus>
            </PartReceipt>
         </PartReceipts>
      </Receipt>
   </Receipts>
</ReceiptConfirmation>
```

The xslt I am using is

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:template match="/">
<File>
<xsl:for-each select="ReceiptConfirmation/Receipts">
<xsl:for-each select="ReceiptConfirmation/Receipts/Receipt/PartReceipt">
    <ReceiptConfirmation>
    <FileNumber><xsl:value-of select="ReceiptConfirmation/File/FileNumber"/>        
</FileNumber>
    <FileCreationDate><xsl:value-of select="ReceiptConfirmation/File/FileCreationDate"/>    
</FileCreationDate>
    <FileCreationTime><xsl:value-of select="ReceiptConfirmation/File/FileCreationTime"/>        
</FileCreationTime>
    <InboundID><xsl:value-of select="ReceiptConfirmation/Receipts/Receipt/InboundID"/>    
</InboundID>
    <ReceiptID><xsl:value-of select="ReceiptConfirmation/Receipts/Receipt/ReceiptID"/>        
</ReceiptID>
    <Vendor><xsl:value-of select="ReceiptConfirmation/Receipts/Receipt/Vendor"/>    
</Vendor>
        <ReceiptDate><xsl:value-of             
select="ReceiptConfirmation/Receipts/Receipt/ReceiptDate"/></ReceiptDate>
<ReceiptTime><xsl:value-of     
select="ReceiptConfirmation/Receipts/Receipt/ReceiptTime"/></ReceiptTime>
<ReceiptType><xsl:value-of     
select="ReceiptConfirmation/Receipts/Receipt/ReceiptType"/></ReceiptType>
<PartRef><xsl:value-of 
select="ReceiptConfirmation/Receipts/Receipt/PartReceipts/PartReceipt/PartRef"/>
</PartRef>
<QtyExpected><xsl:value-of         
select="ReceiptConfirmation/Receipts/Receipt/PartReceipts/PartReceipt/QtyExpected"/>
</QtyExpected>  
<QtyReceived><xsl:value-of select="ReceiptConfirmation/Receipts/Receipt/PartReceipts/PartReceipt/QtyExpected"/>
</QtyReceived>  
<StockStatus><xsl:value-of 
select="ReceiptConfirmation/Receipts/Receipt/PartReceipts/PartReceipt/QtyExpected"/>    
</StockStatus>  
</ReceiptConfirmation>

</xsl:for-each>
</xsl:for-each>
</File>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I need some help to setting up loop between two nodes and getting the result using xslt.

This what I am expecting.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ReceiptConfirmation>
<Receipt>
<FileNumber>11520</FileNumber>
  <FileCreationDate>2014-02-11</FileCreationDate>
  <FileCreationTime>20:50:23</FileCreationTime>
  <InboundID>2136</InboundID>
  <ReceiptID>R00706</ReceiptID>
  <Vendor>DayMen</Vendor>
  <ReceiptDate>2013-12-11</ReceiptDate>
  <ReceiptTime>11:32:21</ReceiptTime>
  <ReceiptType>RMA</ReceiptType>
  <PartRef>JB00128-CEN</PartRef>
  <QtyExpected>2</QtyExpected>
  <QtyReceived>2</QtyReceived>
  <StockStatus>Inspection</StockStatus>
</Receipt>
<Receipt>
  <FileNumber>11520</FileNumber>
  <FileCreationDate>2014-02-11</FileCreationDate>
  <FileCreationTime>20:50:23</FileCreationTime>
  <InboundID>2136</InboundID>
  <ReceiptID>R00706</ReceiptID>
  <Vendor>DayMen</Vendor>
  <ReceiptDate>2013-12-11</ReceiptDate>
  <ReceiptTime>11:32:21</ReceiptTime>
  <ReceiptType>RMA</ReceiptType>
  <PartRef>JB00129-CEN</PartRef>
  <QtyExpected>2</QtyExpected>
  <QtyReceived>2</QtyReceived>
  <StockStatus>Inspection</StockStatus>
</Receipt>
<Receipt>
  <FileNumber>11520</FileNumber>
  <FileCreationDate>2014-02-11</FileCreationDate>
  <FileCreationTime>20:50:23</FileCreationTime>
  <InboundID>2136</InboundID>
  <ReceiptID>R00706</ReceiptID>
  <Vendor>DayMen</Vendor>
  <ReceiptDate>2013-12-11</ReceiptDate>
  <ReceiptTime>11:32:21</ReceiptTime>
  <ReceiptType>RMA</ReceiptType>
  <PartRef>JB00130-CEN</PartRef>
  <QtyExpected>2</QtyExpected>
  <QtyReceived>2</QtyReceived>
  <StockStatus>inStock</StockStatus>
</Receipt>
</ReceiptConfirmation>
```

Comment: Can you show the output you are expecting in this case? It would also help a little if you indented the XML a bit, to make it slightly easier to read. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for replying, actually I am new to stackoverflow....

Comment: I know nothing about SSIS. In general, importing a nested XML file into a relational database requires multiple imports - and each import will use its own XSLT stylesheet. In this case, you would want a stylesheet to import the receipt/s into a Receipts table, and another stylesheet for importing the PartReceipts into another table (a child of Receipts). The value of ReceiptID would be output by both stylesheets, so that you can use it in order to join the two tables.

Comment: I have modified the xml.

Comment: IMHO, your output doesn't match your input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think (or guess) this will do what you want:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
    <ReceiptConfirmation>
        <xsl:for-each select="ReceiptConfirmation/Receipts/Receipt/PartReceipts/PartReceipt">
            <Receipt>
                <xsl:copy-of select="ancestor::ReceiptConfirmation/File/*"/>
                <xsl:copy-of select="ancestor::Receipt/*[not(*)]"/>
                <xsl:copy-of select="*"/>
            </Receipt>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </ReceiptConfirmation>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: @user3410172 Note that this may be a good XSLT solution, but it is not a good database solution (storing the same data in multiple records).

Comment: I am only using XSLT to denormalize XML file. to feed data into data base I am using openrow for bulk insert

Comment: @user3410172 That's exactly my point: a database *should* be normalized.